# Creating Quarkus Docker Container with mandrel fails

Tags: docker, quarkus

I want to create a docker container based on a mandrel-image and followed this guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#multistage-docker

However, neither for multistage nor for just modifying the Dockerfile.native to use the mandrel image it works. If I use the Dockerfile.native which is part of the getting-started project and modify it just in terms of the FROM clause and the basic image to use

```
FROM quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:21.2.0.1-Final-java11 AS build
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I'll get the following build error:

```
 => ERROR [3/4] RUN chown 1001 /work     && chmod "g+rwX" /work     && chown 1001:root /work                       1.0s
------
 > [3/4] RUN chown 1001 /work     && chmod "g+rwX" /work     && chown 1001:root /work:
#6 0.915 chown: changing ownership of '/work': Operation not permitted
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c chown 1001 /work     && chmod "g+rwX" /work     && chown 1001:root /work]: exit code: 1
```

On the other hand, if I use the dockerfile shown on the website and replace the FROM clause

```
FROM quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:21.2.0.1-Final-java11
WORKDIR /work/
COPY target/*-runner /work/application
RUN chmod 775 /work
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

the build finishes, but when I try to run it, I get the following error

```
[./application:51]    classlist:   4,403.97 ms,  0.96 GB
Error: Main entry point class './application' not found.
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
[./application:51]      [total]:   4,467.02 ms,  0.96 GB
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

What am I missing here? Do you have an idea how I can a running mandrel-based native container with quarkus?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not clear what you end goal is. Are you simply trying to use the mandrel container image and don't want to use a multi-stage build?

Comment: My main goal is to have a mandrel-based docker container image with a native executable. Whether I'm creating it manually step-by-step (build native executable, create container) or doing it right away in a multistage approach is not significant to me. I'm just fine with it if one of the approaches will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of images when it comes to Quarkus native executable.

- **Builder image** - an image that contains Mandrel distro, JDK, C compiler, libraries, all the necessary tooling.
- **Runtime image** - a barebone image containing just the final Quarkus native executable, C runtime and necessary runtime libraries (e.g. zlib).

So, you can use the **Builder image** Quarkus pulls and controls for you to build your application into a native executable, e.g.

```sh
./mvnw clean package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:21.3-java11
```

...and then you can just use a Dockerfile like this to stuff that resulting binary executable in that **Runtime image**:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.4
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

If you don't want Quarkus to control that **Builder image** for you and you'd like to have your own multistage build, you can do so too.

E.g. with this example Quarkus app:

```sh
curl -O -J  https://code.quarkus.io/d?e=io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy
unzip code-with-quarkus.zip 
cd code-with-quarkus/
rm .dockerignore
vim Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:21.3-java11 as nativebuilder
WORKDIR /work/
USER root
COPY src /work/src
COPY .mvn /work/.mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml /work/
RUN ./mvnw clean package -Pnative

FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-micro:8.4
COPY --from=nativebuilder \
   /lib64/libz.so.1 \
   /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 \
   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 \
   /lib64/libbz2.so.1 \
   /lib64/libm.so.6 \
   /lib64/libbz2.so.1 \
   /lib64/libexpat.so.1 \
   /lib64/libuuid.so.1 \
   /lib64/
USER 1001
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --chown=1001:root --from=nativebuilder /work/target/*-runner /work/application
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

and then

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t my-quarkus-test .  
docker run -i  -p 8080:8080 my-quarkus-test:latest
```

You definitely should play with caching the maven stage, e.g. working with `dependency:go-offline` so as you don't download the whole Internet in the nativebuilder each time.

Last but not least, if you use `ubi-minimal` instead of `ubi-micro` you can omit copying those `/so` files for the price of having a slightly bigger image size on disk. It does not affect your runtime app memory footprint though.

Let me know if it helped, I appreciate feedback immensely.